# Userscript for easily replying in Stack Exchange chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, stackexchange, chat, userscript

In SE chat, there are two different ways to mention people: A "ping" to just get a user's attention, and a "reply" that points out a specific message by the user. This script makes it so that beginning a message with (by default) `@username@`, the message is made a reply to `username`'s most recent message. Additionally, any message that begins with `@username*` is never sent, but `username`'s last message is starred.

I have very little experience with Javascript, and even less with jQuery. I wrote this code flying by the seat of my pants. I googled a lot of things, referenced a lot of things used in [this script](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/sevichat), and guessed at a lot of others. It works, sure, but that last sentence doesn't inspire a lot of confidence. I don't really have anything specifically I want to ask about, since I don't know what stuff it is that I don't know! :P That being said, I'm sure there are probably a lot of problems with it that someone more experienced than I would be able to identify.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name easyreply
// @namespace http://reddit.com/u/undergroundmonorail
// @author monorail
// @version 0.2
// @description easily respond to a user's last message in se chat
// @grant none
// @copyright MIT
// @include *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @include *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

// workaround for Safari
// (as if anyone uses Safari)
// ((glares at @AlexA.))
function withJQuery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.textContent = '('+ f + ')(jQuery)';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

withJQuery(easyreply);

function easyreply($) {
    // OPTIONS
    // prefix/suffix of username to reply to
    var R_PREFIX = '@';
    var R_SUFFIX = '@';
    // prefix/suffix of username to star
    var S_PREFIX = '@';
    var S_SUFFIX = '*';

    var input = $('#input');

    function messageAuthor(message) {
        // a group of continuous messages by the same user is a "monologue"
        // go up to the monologue, then find the author
        // strip spaces from the username because that's how the name you type to ping someone is found
        // (e.g.) pinging 'Alex A.' is done by typing '@AlexA.')
        return message.parent().parent().children('.signature').children('.username').text().replace(/ /g, '');
    }

    function lastMessageFrom(author) {
            // go backwards through the messages until finding one that is by the mentioned user OR there are no more messages
            var message = $('.message:last');
            while (message.length && author.toLowerCase() !== messageAuthor(message).toLowerCase()) {
                var prev = message.prev('.message'); // go up one message
                if (!prev.length) { // handle monologue barriers
                    // stole this code wholesale from doorknob. i mostly understand it.
                    prev = message.closest('.monologue').prevAll('.monologue').eq(0).find('.message:last');
                }
                message = prev;
            }
            return message; 
    }

    function replyToMessage(message) {
        if (message.length) { // if a message was found
            // reply syntax is ':[message id]'
            // messages have the attribute 'id', containing 'message-[message id]'
            // put a colon, everything after the hyphen in the id, then the original message minus the first word
            input[0].value = ':' + message.attr('id').split('-')[1] + ' ' + input[0].value.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        }
    }
1   
    function starMessage(message) {
        message.find('.stars:first .vote').click();
    }

    input.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) { // when enter key is pressed
            e.preventDefault();

            var firstWord = input[0].value.split(' ')[0];
            var R_author = firstWord.slice(R_PREFIX.length, -R_SUFFIX.length); // author name if reply
            var S_author = firstWord.slice(S_PREFIX.length, -R_SUFFIX.length); // author name if star

            if (R_PREFIX + R_author + R_SUFFIX === firstWord) {
                replyToMessage(lastMessageFrom(R_author));
            } else if (S_PREFIX + S_author + S_SUFFIX === firstWord) {
                starMessage(lastMessageFrom(S_author));
                input[0].value = ''; // no message is sent, clear input box manually
            }
        }
    });

    // i don't know what this means but doorknob's code has it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    var kdevts = $('#input').data('events').keydown;
    kdevts.unshift(kdevts.pop());
    // doorknob: "For the record, it moves the last keydown event to the front of the 'list' of events."
    // "That way your function is called before SE's default functions."
    // "Otherwise, the message would be sent *before* the replacement would be made."
    // thanks doorknob
}
```

Comment: could you explain me why you need that workaround for Safari? What issue is it trying to solve?

Comment: @Zorgatone My understanding is that Safari doesn't let you access the webpage's jQuery from a userscript, but will let you access it from  a `script` element on the page. To be 100% honest I haven't tested this script in Safari at all (I don't even think it's available for Linux and I haven't had easy access to Windows since I wrote it) but this code is based on [a userscript](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/sevichat/blob/master/sevichat.user.js) that does have that and is written by someone I trust to know what they're doing. :P

Comment: Well ok. Good to know

Comment: That kinda sucks though. I don't like exposing a global function for a purpose like this, when you shouldn't.. :( I always have an IIFE or any kind of closure to keep stuff clean and safe

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite nice, so I don't have that much to say about it. Here are a few points I noticed about it.

---

### Store the used array element.

At the beginning of your code, you do this:

> ```
> var input = $('#input');
> ```

Now, everywhere else when you are using this `input` variable, you are doing this:

> ```
> ...input[0]...
> ```

Wouldn't it be a lot more efficient to just store this value in the first place?

```
var input = $('#input')[0];
```

Now you don't have to keep on constantly accessing this array index.

---

### Simplify with regex

After creating some sample chat messages and looking over them, this is the format that special beginning part of the chat message:

```
/^@(.+)(@|*)/
```

In case, you aren't familiar with regex:

- `^@`: The first character must be a @.
- `(.+)`: This grabs the username portion
- `(@|*)`: After the username, there must either a @ or *.

Now, let's use this chat message as an example:

> "@SirPython@ You are so cool!"

Using this regex and `.split` on this string will yield this array:

> ```
> [
>     "",
>     "SirPython",
>     "@",
>     " You are so cool!"
> ];
> ```

*Note: The "@" of the array is that last @, not the first one. Therefore, it could be a **

See how this could be useful now? In the `keydown` listener function, you can use this regex to cleanly parse the chat message and handle the different parts:

```
// If this chat message doesn't use the special part, stop right away
if(!regex.test(string)) {
    return;
}

var parts = input.value.split(regex);
var author = parts[1];
var isReply = parts[2] === "@";
var message = parts[3];

if(isReply) {
    replyToMessage(lastMessageFrom(author));
} else {
    starMessage(lastMessageFrom(author));
    input.value = "";
}
```

See? This code is much cleaner now that it doesn't have to do those weird string slicing operations and what-not. Also, it doesn't need those specific `R_PREFIX` and `S_PREFIX` variables, nor does it need the `R_author` or `S_author` variables (which, by the way, were the same exact thing).

Also, it is more efficient because it now has an *immediate return* if the chat message doesn't meet the format.

The regex, which should be placed near the top of the `easyreply` function so it has time to load, shows cleanly the desired format of the chat message. If you want, since the return from `.split(regex)` can be sort-of weird, you can create some constants to label the indexes to make your code even cleaner.

For example:

```
parts[AUTHOR_INDEX];
```

to get the author.